# django url regex

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I want my urls.py to capture a long url setting as such:

```
/get/<lowercase_string>/<integer>/<date>/<date>/
```

For instance: `www.mysite.com/get/ams/221/12-23-2010/01-10-2011/`, as you may see date is in month/day/year format.

As my regex knowledge is near to nothing, I will be grateful for you guidance. I will be capturing `<lowercase_string>`, `<integer>`, `<date>`, `<date>` parts at my view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
^get/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/

#to capture the values in variables:

^get/(?P<lowercase_string>[a-z]+)/(?P<integer>\d+)/(?P<date1>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/(?P<date2>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/
```

Comment: @arielnmz It's okay.. just fyi: you can revert a vote by clicking again.

Comment: They have to edit the question first since it has been quite some time since I downvoted.